# How to divide the point cloud without duplicate?

Tags: pytorch, point, point-clouds

I want to group some point clouds without duplicate

Hi, I want to divide Point cloud!

for example I have some point cloud (B,N,C) // B is Batch, N is Num of points, C is feature(xyz,RGB..)

So I want to divide it with **K**!

I want to group K pieces each in nearest way **without duplication**!

ex) If k = 8 , I want to make dimension (B,N//8,8,C) then how can I do?
Can I just use reshape or view in torch?
or something different way?

**I've already thought about K-nearest, but it seems that there is overlap.**

Comment: What do you mean by nearest way? Based on proximity of (x,y,z)? Why is there an overlap with K-nearest then?

Comment: Did you try applying a K-mean clustering algorithm?